# how to run a wmi query in c

Tags: c, wmi

i know how to this in .net i want to know how in pure c and not c++

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the COM interface to use WMI from pure C applications. WMI COM Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using OLE you resolves instance of class ManagementClass and follow resolving all other interfaces.
Also (if you use MSVC compiler) you can use #import directive to expose expected dll

Look at this sample on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392093(VS.85).aspx